# Apache 2.4: Restrict access to reverse proxy by IP range, and redirect requests from all other hosts

Tags: apache-httpd, access-control, rewrite

We have a front-end proxy server that serves pages from a back-end website (both running Apache 2.4):

```
# Apache config snippet from frontend server
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass "/blah"  "https://backend.invalid/blah"
ProxyPassReverse "/blah"  "https://backend.invalid/blah"
```

(In other words, accessing anything under https://frontend.invalid/blah actually retrieves the content from the back-end site. This is working as expected.)

In order to do some maintenance work on the back-end site, I would now like to only allow access to the proxy (and backend site) from certain IP ranges (something like `Require ip 123.123  172.20.0.0/16` (etc, for several ranges), and for all requests **not** from within these ranges, redirect those requests to a different site with a status page instead.

I suspect that this will require either some fairly complicated `mod_rewrite` config (always a "several coffees required" task) and/or possibly use of the `If` and `Else` directives.

Can anyone advise how best (or, perhaps, how simplest) to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something in your use case, you could probably simply use an `<If>` directive with the [`-ipmatch` operator](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html), combined with a [`Redirect` instruction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

```
<If "! ( %{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '172.20.0.0/16' )">
    Redirect https://other.com/...
</If>
```

If you need to switch on the original IP — not the (possibly) proxied origin IP — of the user agent which initiated the request, then also enable the [*mod_remoteip* module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) and use variable `CONN_REMOTE_ADDR` instead of `REMOTE_ADDR`.

(...so maybe just barely long enough a task for a few sips of coffee ;)

Comment: Thanks, that looks worth looking into. Do you know if the `-ipmatch` argument can accept multiple IP ranges? Unfortunately, there are several different ranges that we need to allow access from.

Comment: I'm afraid, I have never used that operator besides the test I did on my server to make sure that the example I provided worked, and the documentation doesn't say much about it. My guess is that it only works with single ranges, but you can always try coma-, space- or semicolon-separated lists and see what happens. Most likely I believe, you'll need a compound expression, such as ```"! ( %{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '11.22.33.44/16' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '22.33.44.55/24' || ... )"```.

Comment: @dave559, I'm curious, did my suggestion work with your configuration?